# Handling Conflicting @openzeppelin/contracts Versions in Hardhat Project

Tags: openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts, npm, version-pragma

I am currently working on a Hardhat project that requires the integration of two custom dependencies, namely `custom-dep-a` and `custom-dep-b`. Unfortunately, these two dependencies rely on different versions of `@openzeppelin/contracts`:

- `custom-dep-a` uses `@openzeppelin/contracts@3.4.1-solc-0.7-2`
- `custom-dep-b` uses `@openzeppelin/contracts@4.8.3`

Both of these dependencies import OpenZeppelin contracts with the same base path, i.e., `@openzeppelin/contracts`. This presents a problem because I cannot simply install both versions of the `@openzeppelin/contracts` without causing a conflict.

I have considered a few possible solutions:

1. **NPM Aliases**: Using npm aliases to install two versions of the same package under different names. However, this would require modifying the import paths in `custom-dep-a` and `custom-dep-b`, which is not ideal as I do not wish to alter these dependencies directly.
2. **Forking One Dependency**: Another solution would be to fork one of the dependencies and change its import paths to use a specific OpenZeppelin version. This also isn't a favorable option since it would create a maintenance overhead for any updates in the original dependency.
3. **Manually Handle Dependencies**: Manually download the necessary contracts from the conflicting OpenZeppelin versions and modify the dependencies to point to these local versions. This is a cumbersome approach and makes future updates challenging.

Given the above considerations, none of the solutions are particularly appealing due to the reasons mentioned.

Are there any recommended practices, tools or hardhat plugins that can resolve these kinds of version conflicts in Hardhat projects without modifying the dependencies directly?

Comment: What are the custom-dep-a/b - the npm packages / files / folders?

Comment: @tenbits those are private repos, but for the sake of testing you could assume that `custom-dep-a` is [v3-periphery@main](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/main) and `custom-dep-b` is [v3-periphery@0.8](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/tree/0.8) since they install similar versions of OZ.